# Moving between buttons using Tab on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion

So on Windows, when you have a popup you can navigate through the options using `Tab`, but on my Mac it doesn't work.

I have a screenshot for you to see what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an option to turn this on in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*.

[image]